# In what circumstances does Firebase trigger OnCanceled()

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to cover all cases of failure in firebase/firestore.  I've seen functions trigger OnFailure callback, but under what circumstances does OnCanceled get triggered?  I haven't been able to force any triggers of OnCanceled() for a variety of functions such as writes/deletes as well as operations on FirebaseUser and AuthUI and haven't seen any documentation.  Are these cases documented somewhere?

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/test").setValue("blabla")
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                    {
                        Log.v("TEST", "DB WRITE SUCCESS");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.v("TEST", "DB WRITE FAILURE " + e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCanceled()
                    {
                        Log.v("TEST", "DB WRITE CANCELLED");
                    }
                });

      FirebaseFirestore fs = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fs.collection("users").document("blabla").set(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                    {
                        Log.v("TEST", "FS WRITE SUCCESS");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.v("TEST", "FS WRITE FAILURE " + e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCanceled()
                    {
                        Log.v("TEST", "FS WRITE CANCELLED");
                    }
                });

FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                            .setDisplayName(name)
                            .build();
                   
                    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                                {
                                    Log.v("NICK", "SUCCESS UPDATED PROFILE");
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onCanceled()
                                {
                                    Log.w("NICK", "CANCELED UPDATE PROFILE");
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.w("NICK", "FAILED TO UPDATE PROFILE");
                                }
                            });

AuthUI.getInstance().delete(this)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                            {
                                Log.v("AUTHUI", "SUCCESS DELETED ACCNT");
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onCanceled()
                            {
                                Log.w("AUTHUI", "CANCELED DELETE ACCNT");
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.w("AUTHUI", "FAILED TO DELETE ACCNT " + e);

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Have you tried reading this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener#onCancelled(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError)?

Comment: This is for the listener - there are only two options onDataChange and OnCanceled.  But writes and many other functions return Tasks which have OnFailure and OnCanceled.

Comment: Hmmm, right. So maybe https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task?

Comment: That's the definition of the abstract Task class.  The question is whether or not any of the firebase components ever cancel any of these specific tasks.  Judging by Doug's answer - NO.  And maybe this "cancel" feature is only meant for an external cancellation - I don't know, not enough experience.  So I have to verify for all firebase components that OnCancelled is never triggered internally.

Comment: Well, all those methods (firebase one, at least) returns a task so maybe it's not a bad idea check that documentation... Too bad that documentation itself it's not clear about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> under what circumstances does OnCanceled get triggered?

It doesn't.  Task cancelation only happens for tasks that are specifically designed to be cancelable.  That doesn't happen to Firestore tasks.

Comment: Assume the same holds for AuthUI and FirebaseUser?

Comment: Unless the API documentation for the API that provides the task says that it can be canceled, then it can't be canceled. As far as I know, there are no Firebase APIs that implement cancelation, but you should always check the docs.